# FileMaker API, ask my database to have several table

Tags: php, sql, web, filemaker

I'm searching for a method to ask my database in PHP with **FileMaker** to do :

`SELECT *
 FROM mytable, mytable2, mytable3
 WHERE mytable.primar_key = mytable2.foreign_key
 AND mytable2.foreign_key = mytable3.primar_key`

Something like : `$findCommand =& $fm->newFindAllCommand('mytable','mytable2');
 $findCommand ->addFindCriterion('mytable2.foreign_key', 'mytable.primar_key');`

Or something like : `$findCommand->executeQuery("MY_QUERY_SQL");`

I'm waiting for your answers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a SQL expert, using it in FileMaker quite sparsely (but with ever greater frequency), so I don't fully understand what your SQL code is doing, but FileMaker does have an `ExecuteSQL()` function that would probably return what you want, so the question then becomes how to give the PHP API access to that function.

The API can execute a FileMaker script and a FileMaker script could run the SQL query and store the results in a global text field. However, you're going to get a textual representation of the results, not a PHP FileMaker_Result object, so you'd need to parse the text yourself and translate into a useful form.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the best way to handle such problems is to leverage what FileMaker can offer you out of the box.

So, if you have three related tables here's what I'd do:

1. create a new layout in FileMaker based on TableOccurence1
2. on that new layout, put all the fields you need from TableOccurence1, related TableOccurence2 and related TableOccurence3
3. in php create a new search based on that layout

.

```
$request = $fm->newFindAllCommand('yourNewLayout'); // will give you all records
$result = $request->execute();
$records = $result->getRecords();
```

The reason I called those table "TableOccurence1" is because you need to make sure you base your layout on the table occurrence that has the appropriate relationships to the other two tables.